# Join and get only single row with respect to each id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My question is simple. I have two tables, a `product` table and an `image` table with multiple images of each product.

`Product` table

```
+-----------+-------------+
| productId | ProductName |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 | product1    |
|         2 | product2    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

`Image` table:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+--+
| imageId | imagePath | productId |  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--+
|       1 | img1      |         1 |  |
|       2 | img2      |         1 |  |
|       3 | img3      |         2 |  |
|       4 | img4      |         2 |  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+--+
```

I want to get an output as below

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+--+
| productId | productName | imageId | imagePath |  |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+--+
|         1 | product1    |       1 | img1      |  |
|         2 | product2    |       3 | img3      |  |
+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+--+
```

i.e. there should be only a single image corresponding to each product.

Currently I have done this with cursor, but as an optimization I have to find another way. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do you determine which image? Do you need to get the `Top 1 image from image order by imageId` for each `productid`?

Comment: yes top 1 image. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only one imageId (the minimum) per each productId by joining to filtered imageId like this :

```
SELECT p.ProductId, ProductName, i.imageId, imagePath
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN Image i 
        ON i.ProductId = p.ProductId
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT MIN(imageId) As imageId, ProductId
         FROM image
         GROUP BY ProductId
         ) o 
         ON o.imageId = i.imageId
```

or by filtering imageId using `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT p.ProductId, ProductName, imageId, imagePath
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN Image i 
        ON i.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE imageId IN
    (SELECT MIN(imageId) As imageId
     FROM image
     GROUP BY ProductId
     )
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/53149/6)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 I did this with a nested query that found min or max imageId grouped by productId.  Maybe there's a better way in 2008.

```
select 
  productId, 
  productName,
  minImageId,
  imagePath
from
  product inner join (
    select
      productId,
      min(imageId) as minImageId
    from
      Image
    group by 
      productId) minImages
  on
    product.id = minImages.productId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to do this, like this

```
With FirstImage as(
  Select min(imageid) imageid,
         productid
  From Image
  Group by
  productid)

Select p.productid,
       p.productname,
       i.imageid,
       i.imagepath
from FirstImage fi
inner join image i on i.imageid=fi.imageid
inner join product p on p.productId=i.productid
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fb73/4)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT ProductId, ProductName, imageId, imagePath
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN Image i 
        ON i.ProductId = p.ProductId
WHERE imageId IN
    (SELECT MIN(imageId) As imgId, ProductId
     FROM image
     GROUP BY ProductId
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make this query more simplified by using COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION.We can do like this also

```
DECLARE @X TABLE (ProductID INT,ProductName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @x(ProductID,ProductName)VALUES (1,'Product1')
INSERT INTO @x(ProductID,ProductName)VALUES (2,'Product2')
select * from  @x
Declare @y TABLE(Imageid INT,ImagePath Varchar(20),ProductID INT)
INSERT INTO @y(Imageid,ImagePath,ProductID)VALUES (1,'Img1',1)
INSERT INTO @y(Imageid,ImagePath,ProductID)VALUES (2,'Img2',1)
INSERT INTO @y(Imageid,ImagePath,ProductID)VALUES (3,'Img3',2)
INSERT INTO @y(Imageid,ImagePath,ProductID)VALUES (4,'Img4',2)

;WITH CTE AS 
(
Select x.ProductID,x.ProductName,Y.Imageid,y.ImagePath from @X x
INNER JOIN @y Y
ON x.ProductID = Y.ProductID 
--GROUP BY x.ProductID,x.ProductName

)

Select ProductID,ProductName,MIN(Imageid),MIN(ImagePath) FROM CTE
GROUP BY ProductID,ProductName
```